# iPhone on 3G network SOAP Request Speed

Tags: iphone, xcode, soap, httprequest

Can someone please help me with this ?

I develop an application for iPhone that needs to communicate with my webservice (I use SOAP to communicate and TOMCAT as the web server). When I run the application on my iPhone4 with WiFi connection, it has no problem at all. I have a very fast response from the webserver.

However, when I use my 3G network (Vodafone in Australia), I realized that the response time is not in the acceptable level. Can someone please tell me what I should do to improve the performance ?

[image: Image of Charles Proxy debugging tool]

*In my iPhone App, I have tried: `NSURLConnection synchronous, asynchronous and ASIHTTPFormRequest.` But in terms of performance, they are the same ! :(

*What confused me a lot is that, when I do YouTube, it works very fast without delay on my 3G network.*

Thanks a lot for your time Guys. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you can provide radically less data, you have no control over your carrier's 3G network speed. Even if you use less data, estabikishing the connection can take a while.

Comment: So, I can do nothing about it ? :(